# /etc/environment does not set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables, etc

I have placed Java related info to `etc/environment`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games /usr/local/jdk-9.0.1/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk-9.0.1"
```

Then `source /etc/environment` I expect that it will register JAVA_HOME in exports.

Command `export` gives a list with updated `PATH`, but I can't find `JAVA_HOME` there. Why?

Answer (score 2):

It's explained by the following: the `/etc/environment` file *is not a shell script* and contains only properties that read when the system starts. The `source` command is used to launch shell scripts in the current console. You can restart your system to apply the changes or add this lines into the `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` files and start the `source` command for one of them.

Note that properties from the `/etc/environment` file will be applied to all of the users; the lines from the `~/.profile` file only for defined one.